# How can we inject the claims through the custom authorization lambda

Tags: aws-lambda, authorization, aws-sdk-nodejs, aws-authorizer

Previously we used the authorizer type as cognitouserpool so when we send an request to the customAuthorization added API endpoint means in that API event we get the requestContext object inside authorizer object inside claims so based on that we made our applications by using inside cliams there are some user related info like "cognito:username" this is the existing process.
Now I am preparing one custom authorization lambda for my nodejs API's there I want to send claims also to the respective request event i'm getting only requestContext object inside authorizer object im getting the info what i'm sending in the custom authorization lambda I want to inject the claims object also in the custom authorization.

In my custom authorization lambda Im doing first verifying the token by using with these packages 'jsonwebtoken','jwk-to-pem', after we are trying to do generate policy function inside we are sending some required info like "Action","Effect","resource" and with these "context" obj inside what we want to pass required info that use for every lambda event like username, user role etc with this approach we are able to hit the appropriate lambda but I want to inject the claims object also that should come for what API we are hitting in that API event we supposed to get the requestContext object inside authorizer object inside claims as like we are getting previously with the authorizer type of cognitouerpool related event like i want.

Answer (score 0):

When using a custom API Gateway Lambda authorizer, with [Lambda proxy integration](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/set-up-lambda-proxy-integrations.html), you will still receive the access token on your backend in e.g. the `Authorization` header, which lets you parse the claims using a JWT library:

> In Lambda proxy integration, when a client submits an API request, API
> Gateway passes to the integrated Lambda function an event object,
> except that the order of the request parameters is not preserved. This
> request data includes the request **headers**, query string parameters,
> URL path variables, payload, and API configuration data. The
> configuration data can include current deployment stage name, stage
> variables, user identity, or **authorization context** (if any)

If you're not using Lambda proxy integration, you will need to pass the relevant headers to your  Lambda using a mapping template:

https://repost.aws/knowledge-center/custom-headers-api-gateway-lambda

You don't mention whether you're using Lambda proxy integration, in which case the authorizer context is directly passed as part of the input event to the backend function, with individual values accessible as `event.requestContext.authorizer.key`:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-lambda-authorizer-output.html
to the

Be aware of the following:

> You can access the `stringKey`, `numberKey`, or `booleanKey` value (for
> example, "value", "1", or "true") of the context map in a mapping
> template by calling `$context.authorizer.stringKey`,
> `$context.authorizer.numberKey`, or `$context.authorizer.booleanKey`,
> respectively. The returned values are all stringified. Notice that you
> cannot set a JSON object or array as a valid value of any key in the
> context map.

So, you can't have the custom authorizer parse the claims object, and set it as a value on the authorizer context, you will need to set each claim value on the authorizer manually

If you have the option, I will strongly recommend using AWS Lambda Powertools. You will benefit from e.g. [APIGatewayAuthorizerResponse](https://docs.powertools.aws.dev/lambda/python/latest/utilities/data_classes/#api-gateway-authorizer) when writing your authorization logic:

```
...
policy = APIGatewayAuthorizerResponse(
    principal_id=user["id"],
    context=user,
    region=arn.region,
    aws_account_id=arn.aws_account_id,
    api_id=arn.api_id,
    stage=arn.stage,
)

# Conditional IAM Policy
if user.get("isAdmin", False):
    policy.allow_all_routes()
else:
    policy.allow_route(HttpVerb.GET.value, "/user-profile")

return policy.asdict()
```